# Neo4J: Cannot extract single value from Iterable with more than one elements

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I'm new to Spring and trying to get started building an API for an open source webstore with Neo4j. Right now I'm having issues with getting the proper response from custom @Query'ies in the repository.

This is the response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1422223603656,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "message": "Cannot extract single value from Iterable with more than one elements.",
  "path": "/api/v1/articles"
}
```

Here is the query:

```
@Override
@Query("MATCH (a:`Article`)-[r:CATEGORIZED_TO]->() RETURN a.name as name, a.number as number, r.segment as segment")
Result<Article> findAll();
```

And I'm using the repository this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/articles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Iterable<Article> list(
        @RequestParam(value = "segment", required = false) String segment
) {
    Iterable<Article> articles = null;

    Transaction tx = graphDatabase.beginTx();

    try {
        Result result = articleRepository.findAll();

        articles = result.as(Article.class);

        tx.success();
    } finally {
        tx.close();
    }

    return articles;
}
```

Can you spot the problem?

Edit:

Here's the Article class

```
@NodeEntity
public class Article {

  @GraphId
  private Long graphId;

  @GraphProperty
  private String name;

  @Indexed(unique = true)
  private String number;

  @RelatedTo(elementClass = Category.class, type = "BELONGS_TO", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
  Set<Category> categories;

  @RelatedToVia(elementClass = Listing.class, type = "BELONGS_TO", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
  Iterable<Listing> listings;

  public Article() {
  }

  public Article(String name, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
  }

  public Long getGraphId() {
    return graphId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public Collection<Category> getCategories() {
    return categories;
  }

  public Collection<Listing> getListings() {
    return IteratorUtil.asCollection(listings);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share the definition of your `Article` class.

Either use a DTO class with `@QueryResult` annotation or if `Article` is your domain class you have to `return a`

Also the correct method on the `Result` DSL is `.to(Article.class)` not `as()` the latter is for projecting to collections.

Comment: But I want to return a list of all the articles, not a single article.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you did. Just try and return only 'a' in your query and it'll work! Good luck